# How to hide midlet icon in sonyericsson

Tags: java, java-me, midp

help me on this issue which you have stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481723/is-there-a-method-to-change-a-midlet-icon-once-its-downloaded)

"Some newer Sony-Ericsson phones (with the JP8.3 platform onward) have a proprietary java application management API that can only be accessed if your MIDlet is signed by Sony-Ericsson, along with jad properties that allow you to hide your MIDlet icon from the user."

I have developed an application in j2me and i want to check whether i can hide its icon or not.

Comment: The issue you link to doesn't seem to be the same behavior that you describe.  I'm guessing the hiding of the MIDlet icon is for application that are always going to be running on the device, whether in the background or not.  Basically, your first and last sentence confuse what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually , my application is running in background through push registry  and it is listening for a sms from a port.On receiving sms it sends the location coordinates to the sender.
Its a security service which will be provided to the user, so if he lost his phone so he can track that .
We want to hide midlet icon after installation bcoz if some one stole his phone so that we can track him as well without knowing him and also he can't delete that installation.

Answer (score 2):

To hide your application from the user, add the following applications properties to your .jad file:

SEMC-MIDlet-Hidden: Y
SEMC-ShowInActivityMenu: false
SEMC-SuppressJavaIcon: Y

This may not work if your MIDlet hasn't been signed by a certificate trusted by Sony-Ericsson.

These applications properties are all you need to hide an installed application.

SonyEricsson application management system API is not public. You need to get SonyEricson to send you the JavaDoc and binary library for the phones you want to target.

As far as I know, it doesn't allow you to hide an application after it has been installed. But you could use it to uninstall or launch an application or hide the installation process (silent install).

Comment: Which api is used to hide the icon of midlet?