# How to hide the midlet icon on Nokia phones in J2ME?

Tags: java-me, icons, midlet, jad

I have developed a midlet that is supposed to be invoked using Push Registry only. The user must not be able to manually start the app. I have achieved this by checking if the midlet was not invoked through Push Registry, then exit the midlet immediately. but is there any way to hide the app from application folder on Nokia devices?

It seems that it can be done for sonyericsson: [How to hide midlet icon in sonyericsson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781268/how-to-hide-midlet-icon-in-sonyericsson)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I find here that apparently there is no solution: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1695521