# Multiple icon comes in j2me application with multiple midlet

Tags: java, java-me, j2mepolish

I am developing j2me application in that application i have three midlets. One is main midlet and another two is for starting auto services. I am starting auto services (other two midlet) with main midlet with help of PushRegistry.

So my question is i have three midlet so three icon comes in application. I want only one icon for whole application?

Is it possible to create single icon in application with multiple midlet? 
If not then is it possible to start autoservices without midlet?
If not then is it possible to hide other two icon??

Thanks in advance
Yogesh Patel

Comment: Why can't you do all the service handling in your main midlet?

Comment: There is no global method. For the most part it's not possible, though it seems Sony Ericsson implemented a JAD/MANIFEST attribute you can use to do it. This will only work for Sony Ericsson phones though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349477/how-to-hide-the-midlet-icon-on-nokia-phones-in-j2me

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute MIDlet-Icon, MIDlet-Icon is the principal application's icon.
If you use Netbeans, do right clic in Project icon>Properties>Application Descriptor.[image: menu]

[image]